# Which platforms support a Hyper modifier key?

Tags: keyboard, operating-systems

I've seen that some platforms support the modifier key [Hyper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard) (separate from `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift`, `Super/Cmd/Windows` modifier keys).

While this is not a common modifier, It's available in X11, and I read something to to suggest macOS supports it too.

---

Which operating systems support a 5th (Hyper) modifier key?

Comment: I'm guessing that if X11 has it, it's probably because some weird terminal / obscure Unix system way-back-when had such a key, so there's a flag "just in case". Given that virtually nothing I know nowadays has such a thing (discounting the `Fn` key that many laptops have to handle keys with duplicate functions), I don't think it's something you'd want to use even if the OS supports it.

Comment: There are references online for setting up Hyper key on macOS for eg, so assumed this wasn't just X11.

Comment: macOS is based on Unix so that's more-or-less to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

The Hyper modifier key is defined in the [Space-cadet keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard). This type of keyboards used in the [MIT Lisp machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) which ran some dedicated operating systems. These OSes were written from the ground up in [Lisp programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)), such as [Genera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genera_(operating_system)).

Comment: That's it's origin, but it's still available in Ubuntu for eg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys